# How to add a button to a PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, android-button, android-preferences

I'm quite new to Android Development and just came across Preferences.
I found `PreferenceScreen` and wanted to create a login functionality with it. The only problem I have is that I don't know how I could add a "Login" button to the `PreferenceScreen`.

Here's what my `PreferenceScreen` looks like:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/login" android:key="Login">
        <EditTextPreference android:persistent="true" android:title="@string/username" android:key="Username"></EditTextPreference>
        <EditTextPreference android:title="@string/password" android:persistent="true" android:password="true" android:key="Password"></EditTextPreference>
    </PreferenceScreen>
...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The Button should be right under the two `EditTextPreference`s.

Is there a simple solution for this problem? The one solution I found was not working because I use sub `PreferenceScreen`s.

#### Update:

I figured out that i can add buttons this way:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/login" android:key="Login">
        <EditTextPreference android:persistent="true" android:title="@string/username" android:key="Username"></EditTextPreference>
        <EditTextPreference android:title="@string/password" android:persistent="true" android:password="true" android:key="Password"></EditTextPreference>
        <Preference android:layout="@layout/loginButtons" android:key="loginButtons"></Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and the layout file (`loginButtons.xml`) looks that way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="10" 
    android:baselineAligned="false" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:text="Login" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton" android:layout_gravity="left"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Password?" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forgottenPasswordButton"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

So now the buttons appear but I can't access them in code.
I tried it with `findViewById()` but this is returning null. Any ideas how I could access these buttons?

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen

Comment: BTW, @neelabh answer is most simple - you can achieve the required behaviour by specifing event hanlder in the xml-layout: just add `android:onClick="method"` to each button, where method is defined in the activity as `public void method(View v)`.

Answer (score 343):

For the xml:

```xml
<Preference
    app:title="Acts like a button"
    app:key="@string/myCoolButton"
    app:summary="This is a cool button"
/>
```

Then for the java in your `onCreate()`

```java
Preference button = findPreference(getString(R.string.myCoolButton));
button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) { 
        //code for what you want it to do 
        return true;
    }
});
```

This will appear like a normal Preference, with just a title and a summary, so it will look like it belongs.

### Notes

- "Adding app:widgetLayout with some edit icon would make it much more clear for the user." - [Doron Ben-Ari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5860352/doron-ben-ari). Doron expands on this in the comments.
- Older versions of Android used `android:` prefix. Answer is updated with `app:` prefix.

Comment: Many of the pre-loaded google apps use this approach, and thus it is a good idea to follow that! I found a standard grey button looks out of place on a preferences screen, and thanks to you I found a nice way to make it look standardised :)

Comment: @Jakar This doesn't seem to work for me, 2.3.3. It throws a null pointer exception because `findPreference()` returns null

Comment: Make sure that `android:key="key"` and `findPreference("key");` are using the same key.

Comment: actually this does not display a button at all, which will confuse the user and isn't what the OP asked. correct answer to actually show a button is Nicolas's.

Comment: @user636066, it doesn't show a button but it isn't necessarily gonna confuse a user. That depends on the specific implementation of the UI and the `Preference` or `Button` (whichever is used). In some apps I made, a button would not have provided enough info (because `Preference` has the summary) and would have looked out of place with the rest of the app. There are plenty of situations where the `Preference` is a better solution than adding a `Button`. And there are also situations where the converse is true.

Comment: I just noticed that I posted this in 2011 at 1:11. Haha.

Comment: Should have done that 1 month and 11 days later: 11/1/'11 - 1:11 :)

Comment: how can we save this prefrence

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are using PreferenceFragments (API 11 and up), call `findPreference` from `onCreate` of your `PreferenceFragment`, not the `PreferenceActivity`

Comment: Adding app:widgetLayout with some edit icon would make it much more clear for the user.

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari thanks for the suggestion. I added it as a note in my answer. Would it be `app:widgetLayout` or `android:widgetLayout`? I haven't devved android in years & another answer shows a solution with `android:widgetLayout`.

Comment: @Reed `app:widgetLayout` nowadays. With androidx preferences the prefix is always `app`. But for consistency with the answer you might want to make it `android:widgetLayout`, or to change to `app` in the rest of the answer.

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari, thanks. I'll update to app:widgetLayout & leave a note. What would sample code for `app:widgetLayout` look like, to include an edit icon? (also, please check my note to make sure its accurate. thanks!)

Comment: @Reed It's basically the same, apart that you would normally now write the code in override of `PreferenceFragmentCompat:onCreatePreferences()`, not of onCreate(). The value for `app:widgetLayout` is a layout. In the next comment this is my code, AFAIR it is a modification of the androidx code found by layout inspector on the layout of SwitchPreference.

Comment: @Reed `<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
        app:tint="@color/primary_selector"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/edit"
      />
</FrameLayout>`

Comment: `app:widgetLayout="@layout/prefs_edit_icon"` where prefs_edit_icon.xml is the layout file.

Answer (score 50):

I suppouse its too late.
This is what i have done for a Button Preference.

The preference in preference.xml file in xml folder

```
....
    <Preference
        android:key="resetBD"
        android:title="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento"
        android:summary="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento_desc"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_reset_bd_button" 
    ></Preference>
  ...
```

and pref_reset_bd_button.xml in layout folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Button
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/resetButton" 
        android:text="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento_bt" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="resetearBD">

   </Button>
```

Comment: `android:widgetLayout` is the perfect connection between fragments and and preferences (one or both defined in XML). Thanks a lot. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:widgetLayout)

Comment: Hi @Nicolas. Your code work, but one question... How can you do that the button works in a class that extends PreferenceActivity

Comment: Please tell me how to find this button with id "resetButton"
thanks!

Comment: I found using android:layout superior to android:widgetLayout. Using widgetLayout, my button became what I can only describe as layout_alignParentRight="true", but that behavior went away when using android:layout instead

Comment: And I cannot get this to fire an onPreferenceChange or Click event handler

Comment: @BenJima to find the button, you need create a custom Preference class and override onBindView https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/override-layout-of-android-preference/#widget-layout

Comment: Thanks! I substituted `Button` with `ImageButton`. To react on click you should create a method `fun resetearBD(view: View)` in `PreferenceActivity` (you can access `SettingsFragment` from there). If not making this function you will get an error described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392359/could-not-find-method-in-parent-or-ancestor-context.

Answer (score 38):

I wanted to add an Exit link to the preferences and was able to modify Jakar's code to make it work like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
   <PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings">
       <Preference android:title="Click to exit" android:key="exitlink"/>       
   </PreferenceCategory>    
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Originally the 'Preference' was a 'EditTextPreference' which I hand edited.

Then in the class:

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypreferences);

    Preference button = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("exitlink");      
    if (button != null) {
        button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                finish();   
                return true;
            }
        });     
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Works great. That's brilliant !

Answer (score 8):

Add

```
setContentView(R.layout.buttonLayout);
```

Below

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.yourPreference);
```

buttonLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/saveAlarm"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
</ListView>
```

Access Button by:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Your event
    }
});
```

You can get the button on top or on bottom of the screen by putting the button in RelativeLayout:

- top_control_bar
- bottom_control_bar

bottom_control_bar

This worked for me. I hope I can help someone with this piece of code.

Comment: I used this in my app, it keeps the button on top of the list which looks better and is more user friendly for OK and Cancel buttons.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to just add a Button to a preference screen. Preferences are limited to:

```
EditTextPreference
ListPreference
RingtonePreference
CheckboxPreference
```

While using a preference screen, you are limited to the use of these options, and there are no single "button-preference" which could be easily used for your need.

I've been looking for similar functionality, with adding buttons to the preference screen, but it seems like you need to build your own screen for this, managing the change to preferences in your own implementation.

Comment: Had the same problem, If you want a button in your preferences you have to use a selfmade pref screen :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this to access the button!

```
 View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.layoutButtons, null, false);
```

Don't forget to add `android:id` to the LinearLayout that contains the button in **layoutButtons.xml**, i.e.
     `android:id="@+id/mylayout"`

```
 LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) footerView.findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
 Button login = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
 login.setOnClickListener(this);
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
 lv.addFooterView(footerView);

 // Lines 2 and 3 can be used in the same way for a second Button!
```

Comment: dont forget to mark this question as TRUE if u feel i helped u in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also customise the layout of a Preference by overriding `Preference.onCreateView(parent)`. The example below uses an anonymous inner class to make red preferences.

```
    screen.addPreference(
        new Preference(context) {
            @Override
            protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.onCreateView(parent);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                return view;
            }
        });
```

You could use this technique to add a button to the default view.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to catch a user click on one of the Preferences items and your app is using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, then you can do this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
...
>
...
<Preference
    android:key="@string/pref_key_clickable_item"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Can be clicked"
    android:summary="Click this item so stuff will happen"/>
...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Java:

```
@Override
onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {
    if (preference.getKey().equals(getContext().getString(R.string.pref_key_clickable_item))) {
       // user clicked the item
       // return "true" to indicate you handled the click
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Kotlin:

```
override fun onPreferenceTreeClick(preference: Preference): Boolean {
    if (preference.key == context?.getString(R.string.pref_key_clickable_ite)) {
       // user clicked the item
       // return "true" to indicate you handled the click
       return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom layout for the `SettingsFragment.java` i.e `layout_settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
    tools:ignore="NewApi">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarSettings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="@string/fragment_title_settings" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!--this works as the container for the SettingsFragment.java
    put the code for the Button above or below this FrameLayout
    according to your requirement-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="@string/button_sample_text" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then, refer to the layout file in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="....">
      ...............
      ...............
      <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/MyPreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPreferenceThemeOverlay" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
      <item name="android:layout>@layout/layout_settings</item>
</style>
```

And then, in the `onViewCreated()` method of your `SettingsFragment.java`, you 
can use the button like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
                             savedInstanceState) {

        MaterialButton btnSample = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSample);
        btnSample.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Sample Button 
                   clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: Sample Settings Screen with Button]

Answer (score -2):

try android:onClick="myMethod" works like a charm for simple onclick events

Comment: `Preference` has no `onClick` property

Comment: The answer implies `android:onClick` in the attached button view, not in the preference itself.