# Add buttons to PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferences

I want to add a couple buttons to the bottom of my preferences screen for setting defaults and restoring defaults. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen) answer doesn't cover how to do this using PreferenceFragment. What is the recommended way to accomplish this.

Activity that loads the preferences fragment:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);

        // load up the preferences fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( android.R.id.content, new PrefsSettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

PreferenceFragment implementation:

```
public class PrefsSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);  

        addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.preferences);             
    }       
}
```

preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditTextPreference android:key="edit_text_preference_server_address" android:title="@string/preference_server_address"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:key="switch_preference_bat" android:title="@string/preference_bat"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:key="switch_preference_comm" android:title="@string/preference_comm"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:key="switch_preference_dev_mode" android:title="@string/preference_dev_mode" android:defaultValue="true"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but isn't it the same way? you would just have to define your own layout with buttons on the bottom and `addPreferencesFromResource(...)` should populate the listview. Although I do not recommend having buttons floating on the bottom the screen. Unless you mean at the bottom of your list view?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Adding the ListView and Button entry to my activity xml and calling `this.setContentView( R.layout.activity_settings)` after `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( android.R.id.content, new PrefsSettingsFragment()).commit()` gives me a button at the bottom like I wanted. Next up is figuring out how to make the button work.

Comment: as in resetting to defaults? set an `onClickListner()` for the Button and call `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, PREFS_FILENAME, 0, R.xml.preferences, true);` (false if you don't want to overwrite already set preferences, and are just setting defaults for the first time)

Comment: The issue is the buttons are unclickable. I fiddled with it for a while without success so I decided to go with a [simpler approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298370/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-preferencescreen-android). It is also awkward to have the buttons floating at the bottom of the screen. With this approach, they can appear at the end of the preferences list.

Answer (score 10):

I meet the same question, and I found a way to handle this issue.

Overwrite the method onCreateView in PreferenceFragment, using the given the LayoutInfalter by parameters to create your own View, and return this view.

It's my code. I hope this can be helpful

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.set_alarm, null);

        Button save = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.save);
        Button revert = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.revert);
        Button delete = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        revert.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(mId == -1){
            delete.setEnabled(false);
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I modified the previous post a little bit, so that the button will get attached at the bottom of the view.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        Button btn = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        btn.setText("Button on Bottom");

        v.addView(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Overiding (via the IDE, slightly different method signature) the onCreateView in the PreferenceFragment subclass worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Just create your own layout for the settings activity which contains list view with id @android:id/list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in the activity class set the content view before adding preference fragment

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)

        // load up the preferences fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( android.R.id.content, new PrefsSettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the button clickable? My onClickListener is not fired in this case...

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            Button SendLogbtn = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            SendLogbtn.setText("send log file");

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 500);
            SendLogbtn.setLayoutParams(params);

            v.addView(SendLogbtn);

            SendLogbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // do your code 

                }
            });

            return v;
        }
```