# Android Is there a way to add ImageViews to a PreferenceCategory?

Tags: android

Is there a way to add ImageViews to a PreferenceCategory? How?

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen) solution, but i d like to include a layout to a preferenceCategory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your own preference widget by subclassing the [android.preference.Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) class (see for instance [CheckboxPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) and [its source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.java)).

If you goal is to allow choosing an image, see the RingtonePreference class, it allows to pick a ringtone. You could do something similar to pick an image from the gallery.