# Android DialogPreference Layout TextSize

Tags: android, layout, preferences, dialog-preference

I'm using a PreferenceScreen with some different preferences. I'm also using a custom preference extending DialogPreference. Now the fontsize of the custom DialogPreference is different than the font size of the other preferences. I tried to apply a style to the preference activity but I just reached that all fonts got the same size (title and summary).

Is there another way to let all preferences look the same way?
Thanks!

(I took a look at a view other questions to DialogPreferences but I could not find a solution for this, so I hope this isn't too redundant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the predefined Android styles in your custom preference.  For example, use

`@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium`

for normal TextViews, and

`@android:style/TextAppearance.Large`

four your heading TextViews.

Comment: I had to use a custom layout defined in xml like it is described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences) and then set the title textview to TextAppearance.Medium like you said and adjust the margin-left. Now it looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should not have been this hard but it is:

```
 <com.yourpackage.CustomPreference
        android:dialogMessage="@string/summary"
        android:summary="@string/summary"
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:key="preference"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_preference_title"
        />
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:text="test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the summary text view?