# Showing image on ListPreference summary

Tags: android, listpreference

I'm trying to add images on `ListPreference` and I achieved that but on Android API level 15 or higher it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? I have tested this code on 2.2 and 2.3.3 and all works fine!
Here is my code.

```
private void addSummary(Drawable d, Spannable sp) {

    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(Const.IMAGE_ANCHOR);
    builder.append("  ");
    builder.append(sp);
    setTextColor(builder);
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(d);
    int end = Const.IMAGE_ANCHOR.length();

    builder.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    listPreference.setSummary(builder);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using this approach a cleaner approach would be to declare a layout for the preference object and set the `android:layout` parameter of the preference with the resource id of your custom layout.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194194/1186983) is a working code example.