# Custom EditTextPreference

Tags: android, preferences, edittextpreference

I want to customize my `EditTextPreference`, so i added a `TextView` in the left of my `EditTextPreference`.

Here is my code:

```
<EditTextPreference
   android:key="alert_planed_edittext_preference"
   android:title="@string/alert_planed_edittext_preference"
   android:summary="@string/alert_planed_summary_edittext_preference"
   android:dialogTitle="@string/alert_planed_dialog_title_edittext_preference" />
```

That's what i get in my application:

[image]

And i want to customize my EditTextPreference, that's what i want to get:

[image]

I want to add the number in the right, can i do that?

When i click i get this dialog:

[image]

I want the user to be allowed to select only numbers, how can i do that?

Edit:
I found the solution for the second problem:

```
<EditTextPreference
                android:key="alert_planed_edittext_preference"
                android:title="@string/alert_planed_edittext_preference"
                android:summary="@string/alert_planed_summary_edittext_preference"
                android:dialogTitle="@string/alert_planed_dialog_title_edittext_preference"
                android:numeric="integer" />
```

Comment: i think there is an android:layout param for prefs.

Comment: thanks i think that's it. You can add it as an answer

Comment: i found the answer here.
With the help pf "njzk2". Thanks 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences

Answer (score 4):

For you second question, why you do not use a number picker instead of this edittext ?

Example (from [android.dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html))
[image: Example]

and code like this :

```
Public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference {
    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.numberpicker_dialog);
        setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);

        setDialogIcon(null);
    }
    ...
}
```

Regarding your first question, i have to implement a customPreference. You can take example from [IconPreferenceScreen](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_settings/blobs/67efa271bbff6f7ab355f8a0f121eca29a4dbec2/src/com/android/settings/IconPreferenceScreen.java) which is in the settings menu.