# PreferenceScreen Layout in sliding tabview/layout

Tags: android, xml, preferencescreen

How can i include a preference.xml in a  fragment that is in a tab?
All i want is the layout i have my own logic for settings, i just want the standard preferencescreen look.
This is my latest attempt.

```
 <include layout="@xml/preferences"
     android:id="@+id/rtes"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"

>
</include>
```

I thought this would be easier then to copy the look with a standart layout ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android doesnt like to include layouts from the xml folder into layouts from the layoutfolder , i still think this should be possible but i couldnt find a way.
If anyone ses this question use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334930/6752994 and fake it... dumb i know ...