# Where is the layout file of my settings activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I used the `Settings Activity` template to create a new activity in android studio. After creating it, I cannot find the layout file of the activity anywhere. Where can I find the layout file? If there is no layout file for `Settings Activity` template, how can I change its contents?

Android studio also created a new folder called `xml`, does this have anything to with the settings activity?

Comment: Yes, it's in the `xml` folder

Comment: In your Java Settings Activity file, there is probably a reference to a layout/resource file (e.g. in mine there is a line `loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferenceheaders, target);`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Settings Activities typically use preferences defined in an XML file. These aren't exactly layouts, so they are usually placed in the `xml` resource subdirectory. Read more about preference-based settings screens [on this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default the Settings activity extends PreferenceActivity which has a standard layout. The layout is shown in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)
Nonetheless, if you want to change it, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences)