# How to change background,size and color for items in setting activity

Tags: android

How to change size and color for text inside header-preference and how to change background?

Also how can change background and size,color for menu in sub menu.

For example i need display three items for example setting , display , control  this items display in header-reference and need change size and color for this items setting , display , control  also background for preference-header.

Also when press setting open anther menu this is using preference-screen also i need change background for this menu and change size ,color for any item include in this menu.

I am using android studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6194116/4427731

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by this code

in styles

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#25d415</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f50606</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">70px</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorbackground</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

and in manifest put android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in any activity you need

```
<activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLEhO.png)
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di3d1.png)