# Android PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, image, colors, preferencescreen

How to in PreferenceScreen line draw image?

Example with solid color:

[image]

**EDIT**

Preference screen is build programmatically, is not defined in xml layout.
I only use styles in xml.
This not is duplicate as you mark.

**EDIT & ANSWER** is in: [Android: programmatically created image vs resource image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241903/android-programmatically-created-image-vs-resource-image/35270698#35270698)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences/6194194#6194194

Comment: I want do it dynamically, not by the xml