# Android: programmatically created image vs resource image

Tags: android, image, resources, drawing, drawable

**1)** Is it possible to create drawable, example

```
static Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
static Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, conf);
// something draw
// eventually convert to DrawableBitmap
```

and then **convert it / asiggn as / put in** resource, to use in function with resource id param, like:

```
public void setWidgetLayoutResource (int widgetLayoutResId)
```

or
**2)** is it possible to dynamically draw to change image in R.drawable.something.bmp?

All this for change color of widget in setWidgetLayoutResource() to any color, not fixed as color of concrete resource

Comment: can you comment this -1 or question?

Comment: `widgetLayoutResId` is something like `R.layout.*`, so what does it have to do with a `Bitmap`?

Comment: Maybe exist some type conversion object to resource. I dont know and I ask about it. Question is 2 partial. You say 1) or 2) is obvious and certainly impossible?

Comment: xml layouts define UI components and have nothing to do with Bitmaps

Comment: png in resources isn't xml layout

Comment: no, it is not, it is something like R.drawable.*

Comment: in setWidgetLayoutResource (int widgetLayoutResId) is possible set id of drawable png  from res. -1 for you.

Comment: 1? what 1? what do you mean?

Comment: its joke:)  in setWidgetLayoutResource (int widgetLayoutResId) argument may be R.drawable.* not must be R.layout.*

Comment: no, it has to be R.layout.*, see http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java#523

Comment: I know what is in my code and on the device screen, realy

Comment: well, my android studio marks it with lint error `"Expected resource of type layout less... (Ctrl+F1)"` and of course the app crashes but if you say so...

Comment: In my Eclipse no errors and image from R.drawable.* is shown as accesory of the preference screen line

Comment: we are of course talking about `Preference#setWidgetLayoutResource` described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setWidgetLayoutResource(int))? where it clealy states: `widgetLayoutResId The **layout resource ID** to be inflated into the main layout.` and the source code i posted above proves that it is true

Comment: then put drawable to simply layout only with it. all its out of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

**My own answer**

This question is relative to my other:    [Android PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223693/android-preferencescreen)
and I was do it in this way:

**ColorLinesView.java**

```
public class ColorLinesView extends View
{
    private static GradientDrawable gdDefault = new GradientDrawable();
    public static int fillColor;

    public ColorLinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {   super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas cv) 
    {   
       gdDefault.setColor(fillColor);
       gdDefault.setCornerRadius(4);
       gdDefault.setStroke(2, 0xffbbbbbb);
       this.setBackgroundDrawable(gdDefault);
    }
}
```

**color_lines_accesory.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.swp.ColorLinesView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/colorBoxLines"
 android:layout_width="52dp"
 android:layout_height="26dp"
 android:gravity="right"
 android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
```

and finally while programmatically create PreferenceScreen, after add category preference "somePref":

```
ColorLinesView.fillColor = 0xff00ff00; // examply green
somePref.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.color_lines_accesory);
```

and the same two lines (with new color) in OnPreferenceClickListener() for "somePref" category, after using color picker to change color.

result:

[image]

Comment: any reason for making that so complex instead of dreating a custom `Preference`?

Comment: What is "dreating", my english is very simply and I cant find it. You think "treating"?

Comment: sorry, typo: "creating", why not to make a class that extends `Preference`?

Comment: In ColorLinesView.java I have full programmatically control & I may draw what I want. Rest of the preference (icon, summary, title) is controlled by system and the style for whole PreferenceScreen.

Comment: Class extends Preference: I was probe and I have problems with this.

Comment: and now try to use ColorLinesView twice in your PreferenceScreen... too bad as you are using a static field

Comment: yes I know:))) now I work about instantiate my class:). class and variables are the same, but parents not.

Comment: just create a custom Preference, see how other Preferences do that (like CheckBoxPreference for example)

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.java#35 all you need to do your stuff in `onBindView`

Comment: Stuff with adding view to control color + extend preference code as I think is complicated like my ColorLinesView.  Additionally in bindView are problems with get dimensions etc. For me is enough what I make.

Comment: Temoporary because in all of my preference screens (more is this in app) not exist more like 2 color boxes in one window, I was made the same simply class code & xml layout 2 times with different names. In my country says: "Temporary sulutions are most durable" :)))

Comment: and in practice those 20 lines of code make a custom preference: http://pastebin.com/GSTiYBWz

Comment: Pretty small code, but I don't understand how to later dynamically change color ( d.setColor(0xaaff0000)) to any other many times. Where is the trick?

Comment: I work about it but  v.setBackground(new InsetDrawable(gd, 0, 18, 0, 18)) or v.setBackground(gd) not work.

Comment: I really can't do this. About my class instantation: it's simply. getId() is duplicated in other instances, but hashCode() is unique. Simply putInt and getInt (or other) from shared preferences for many paremeters without string coverting. Additionally parent of view (widget layout)  reports rect of the widget field in preference line, parent of parent (LinearLayout) - rect on preference screen. It's flexible.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you are talking about... you are talking about your or my code?

Comment: Yes, my first step is using getId(). Only one class *.java for many widgets, and multiple  widget layout (on one preference screen, many screens may using the same layout). After creating preference: String sn = "ColorWidget_"+Integer.toHexString(R.id.colorBoxDots);
     SWP.preferencesEditorSwp.putInt(sn, SWP.PREF_LogDotsColor); =========== in class onDraw:      String sn = "ColorWidget_"+Integer.toHexString(this.getId());
      fillColor = SWP.preferencesSwp.getInt(sn, 0); =========== Now Im working about using hasCode() in place getId() to define only one widget layout.

Comment: again... does my code work or not? if not, what doesn't work?

Comment: Not. I don't know why. I'm work about it independly. May it depend from styles.xml, I check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103076/discussion-between-skippy-and-pskink).

Comment: the color gradient is not visible 
in any xml style 
do you create preferences in xml or programatically?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JhqEsgVq see the bottom, there are tho `MyPref`s on the `Preferencescreen` (lines 48-63)

Comment: ok I check it later, I dont know what a different from programmatically creating, but all of the options must be checked

Comment: it doesn't matter if you do that in xml or by `PreferenceScreen#addPreference`, both ways work, i just checked the second way

Comment: Well, still nothing,  v.setBackground() not exist, I use v.setBackgroundDrawable(). As I think its only difference. It's mistake in youre code or something in my app?

Comment: hmm, check `View#setBackground()` and `View#setBackgroundDrawable()` javadocs, i use API level 16+

Comment: I havent info about using supress lint new api, but error. Do yoy use Eclipse?

Comment: OK solved, ufff. I dont like unsolved problems:) after v.setVisibility I insert:             v.setMinimumHeight(); v.setMinimumWidth(); and it work.

Comment: if you need `setMinimumHeight` / `setMinimumWidth` then probably there is a better idea to provide a real widget layout by calling `setWidgetLayoutResource` which points to some `ImageView`

Comment: is it connected with `setMinimumHeight` / `setMinimumHeight`? if so, as i said, better provide a real widget layout by calling `setWidgetLayoutResource` which points to some `ImageView` - that way the code in `onBindView` will be just two lines

Comment: no, this is my class onDraw(canvas) and in widget layout "fill_parent" on both dimensions

Comment: but in pref subclassing I think it may be the same

Comment: what onDraw?  Preference does not have such method

Comment: in my class "ColorLinesView  extends View" in my post up, I not edit it

Comment: You dont need it,  just use an ImageView

Comment: your png with big dots is interesting design idea

Comment: `my code is ready pastebin.com/SzPkd3zq` how can you manage that code? compare it to this: http://pastebin.com/BSzFcVKk, why dont you use a custom preference (a class extending `Preference`)?

Comment: I see, with simply color picker. I have more functionally and user friendly class over whole app http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6318/j72PnT.png . I don't understand question "how can you manage". You think about programm vs xml creating? "Why dont use" - if I fail to tackle full instantation problem (one widget xml over one preference screen), I do it.

Comment: Have you seen MyPref?  no id workarounds, everything in a one place, you want a custom picker?  No problem extend just Preference,  not DialogPreference as it adds its own dialog buttons

Comment: I dont want color picker, I have code for this screen shot. MyPref - as I wrote:  if I fail to tackle full instantation problem (one widget xml over one preference screen), I do it. I want solve this problem in my way.

Comment: `In my country says: "Temporary sulutions are most durable"` now it's clear why this happen: you have a right working solution, but still insist on using your temporary code, this is what i cannot undarstand

Comment: when I wrote this, solution contained 3 xmls and 3 classes, now its 3 short xml and 1 common class. temporary state chenged.

Comment: it is still a completely bad practice: just take a look on other `Preference`s you can use: `CheckBoxPreference`,  `EditTextPreference`, `ListPreference` etc, just see their sources and compare them with your code, your way is not a way you should write a custom `Preference`, just follow their way

Comment: That what you say, make setWidgetLayout() nonsense.

Comment: in standard google's `Preference`s they do not call `setWidgetLayoutResource` anywhere, so what nonsense do you mean?

Comment: and if you really want to avoid calling `setWidgetLayoutResource`, [this](http://pastebin.com/Bjj3bY1Z) is a solution that doesn't use any xml files at all (except sample color picker layout) and still you can add your preference either from xml or java code (the complete code has only ~80 lines of java code)

Comment: your project uses api older than android 4.1 and i dont have such emulator so i was not able to run in in pre 4.1 environment, does it work at you?

Comment: I work only on real devices, never on emu. My app min API is 11. But runs without problems on A4 and A5 devices. BTW I dont understand why emu with 4.1 not work with backward compatibility.

Comment: i know it works on A4.1+ (including A5) because i build it and run on those versions, i was asking about versions older than A4.1.. did it work on those?

Comment: Today I cant check it on older device like 4.1. In my code no @SuppressLint("NewApi") compiler commands. targetSdkVersion = 8, as I check now. What goes wrong? PrefrenceScreen creating or widget class?

Comment: earlier i sent you some code (working at me) but you said that you had to add some `v.setMinimumHeight();` / `v.setMinimumWidth()` to make it work, that is why i am asking if the code i posted here: http://pastebin.com/Bjj3bY1Z works or not at you

Comment: Oh yes. In this code all is OK. Eclipse not alarm with "newApi" info. I cant check it on emu or device <4.1. One change are seekbars colors, all seekbars are blue, but img with destination color work properly.  v.setMinimumWidth() I'v must insert in early version of code. In this version - not. I create myPref programmatically: myPref = new MyPref(this, null); myPref.setKey("myPref"); myCategory.addPreference(myPref); not in xml, this only one different.

Comment: good, btw any reason for not defining preferences in xml? it is much easier than `myPref = new MyPref(this, null); myPref.setKey("myPref"); myPref.setTitle("my title");  myPref.setSummary("my summary"); myCategory.addPreference(myPref` and stuff like that

Comment: I always make it programmatically. Normally in own sub-method common for whole code, in one line create new, set key, title etc. This is faster in work for me.

Comment: so if you dont want to use it inside xml, change the constructor and use like this: `myPref = new MyPref(this);`

Comment: please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404956/how-to-get-preferencescreen-line-height