# How to get PreferenceScreen line height?

Tags: android, subclass, preferenceactivity

How to get PreferenceScreen line height depend from xml in Preference subclass?

```
public class MyPref extends Preference{

  @Override
  protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    // Here getTop() & getBottom() is 0:0

  }
}
```

**EDIT & ANSWER**
from: [Android: how to get value of "listPreferredItemHeight" attribute in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982132/android-how-to-get-value-of-listpreferreditemheight-attribute-in-code)

value is in **float listPreferredItemHeight**

```
public class MyPref extends Preference
{

    private float listPreferredItemHeight;

    @Override protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        Context context = getContext();

        android.util.TypedValue value = new android.util.TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
        android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        listPreferredItemHeight = value.getDimension(metrics);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `line height` ? what do you need it for?

Comment: line height in pixels, like other non-sublassed lines on PreferenceScreen

Comment: it is unknown inside `onBindView`, where do you need it for?

Comment: In onCreateView() when I add myView by addView(), where I must define size of view

Comment: first we must set LayoutParams with width & height

Comment: And what size do you want your pref to have?

Comment: like other lines on PrefrenceScreen, depend from styles.xml or default style

Comment: there is no fixed size, each preference could use its own size (depending on what they want to show), you want your pref to fill the entire height in the preferences row?

Comment: yes and no, I want my subclass-preference with the same height as others

Comment: then see `ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int, int)` constructor documentation

Comment: I dont know how to get layoutParams or LinearLaout of preference screen line.

Comment: why do you need LayoutParams of LinearLaout ?

Comment: not "of" but "or". To get line default height in dp or px. To set ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int, int) with height like other lines on the same preference screen. Something like <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">xxdp</item> in styles.xml, what define line height.

Comment: inside `onCreateView` you have `ViewGroup frame = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(android.R.id.widget_frame);` which is a `LinearLayout` but you dont need it at all, just make sure your custom view height matches the parent's height, that's all

Comment: I check it all and more. Frame dimensions 0,0-0,0. Parents height is height of whole list.

Comment: Parent is `frame` view, you are adding your custom view to this view, not to a ListView, use `hierarchyviever` tool to see the whole UI tree

Comment: its from Log, after enumerate all of the parents no one with height what I talk about. Height of list, or 0.

Comment: this is because when `onCreateView` is called every view has empty size (because it is before the "layout" phase), again all you need is to make sure your custom view height matches the parent's height, just read the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` documentation, why dont you want to do that?

Comment: It look not good, when one line have different height from other.

Comment: what line has different height? what is the height of `EditTextPreference` or `CheckBoxPreference` and what is the height of your custom `Preference`?

Comment: see [here](http://pasteboard.co/1A5IeIPi.png), each property has the same height of 64 pixels

Comment: Impossible. It depend from styles.xml and screen density. In my own style line height is defined as <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">36dp</item> what equals 72px (density 2.0)

Comment: I scaled it down two times, the original height was 128 pixels, still each preference has the same height. They dont differ

Comment: It depend from styles.xml or its default. its not always 128px/dp. Problem is: how to get this value universally.

Comment: so tell me why my custom preference has the **same** height than other preferences (i am not using any constants, magic numbers etc)? see http://pasteboard.co/1A5IeIPi.png, and, no, you dont need that value (36dp, 128px, whatever) at all

Comment: On my device with my own styles.xml isnt the same with youre code. This is source of my question. App icon height its bad idea. The rest is very good.

Comment: post the link to your device screen then

Comment: what you use as "size" in "frame.addView(indicatorView...."?

Comment: `Resources#getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);`

Comment: sorry, lines height are the same, but widget have bad size. One moment with images.

Comment: so what that widgets have different size? each preference can use different widgets, with different size and you cannot do anything... would you like to have 16x16 px color indicator because `CheckBoxPreference` uses 16x16 px check box?  android.R.dimen.app_icon_size is commonly used across the platform and that size is not that bad

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/1AMdxLsR.jpg

Comment: I dont understand why system checkboxes on youre screen are so small

Comment: I use own window style and in it:  <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">36dp</item>. Its not commonly across all.

Comment: so instead of `android.R.dimen.app_icon_size` use your own setting equal to 36dp

Comment: but the best idea is just to match the parent height and use some top / bottom padding (8dp for example)

Comment: You see how big is widget? With android.R.dimen.app_icon_size reports 96px, not 72px (36dp) as line real height.

Comment: so as i said, "the best idea is just to match the parent height and use some top / bottom padding (8dp for example)"

Comment: I have write you about size of parents.

Comment: just match the parent height, thats all you have to do, read the docs of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, this is the 3rd time i suggest to read them but you just ignore that

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EPmG0du7

Comment: you are not listening what i am saying,  so i think its a waste of my time here

Comment: Do you know other parents like in my listing?  Answer now is in my question after EDIT. Thx.

Comment: which is the same as: `new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)` (which matches the parent's height), 1 line instead of 6 and you would get it if you read the official documentation

Comment: 2) what if line have summary?

Comment: set the summary and try

Comment: I know what, height reports total height. It;s bad.

Comment: What with width? Magic number "size" in: ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

Comment: read `onMeasure` docs

Comment: ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) its BAD IDEA. Now all is known.