# Using Preference API for a custom object

Tags: android

I'm using Sugar ORM and I have my Reminder model.
I built the "New Reminder" activity manually and it turned out very ugly:[image: New Reminder Activity]

I really like the Preference API (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) which could solve many of my issues. However, I don't need preferences to be saved with SharedPreferences, since I'm manually saving them to Sqlite via Sugar ORM.

Is there a way to use that UI anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `persist*` methods to save your values. If you check [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) class you can see that they are `protected`. You must also override the `getPersisted*` methods to suit your own needs.

Take for example `EditTextPreference`;

You would have to create your own class that extends it like so:

```
 public class MyCustomEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference{
    //custom implementation here
 }
```

See more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom)

Comment: So I should make my activity extend Preference and override those two methods? Then I can use the <PreferenceScreen> XML layout? My activities already extend a BaseActivity which sets up toolbars etc, how can I do it cleanly?

Comment: No. The `Preference` class is the actual "setting" component take a look at my **edit**

Comment: Could you please give me a couple other details to start working on it? Right now I have my EditReminderActivity with the 'saveReminder' method, that will go get values by referencing layout components (such as EditText or Switch or Spinner components, see screenshot). It will then call the Sugar ORM's 'save' method on the entity I'm saving. How should I edit it to use the Preference layout? The layout right now is a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: For a custom layout, take a look a [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences)

Comment: I don't really need to customize the default Preference layout, I just need to understand how to use it correctly in my Activity, while saving data with Sugar ORM instead of SharedPreferences.

Comment: I haven't seen Sugar being used for settings. Please read the [Sugar docs](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) thoroughly

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not using it for settings. I'd like to use the default android preference layout (just the layout), but then I'm saving a standard Sugar ORM Entity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121531/discussion-between-laser-and-koichirose).