# How to include Preference in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Can I include a preference in Layout like how we include a layout in another layout using `<include layout=""/>` tag.

My layout code goes like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<include layout="@layout/settings"/>
<!-- <include layout="@xml/set_variables"/> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

in the above layout i am trying to include preference `@xml/set_variables` but my application will crash if i uncomment `<include layout="@xml/set_variables"/>` . Please can any one suggest is there any way to include preference in layout or just I should forget this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gone through [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760420/add-a-button-to-the-bottom-of-preferences-screen) and found solution
In `onCreate` of `PreferenceActivit`y I have added

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.set_variables);
```

and added `ListView` in `settings` layout

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

it met my requirement