# Android PreferenceScreen Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

hi I am using `Preferencescreen` xml to design my preferences screen ,I am adding two button at bottom of preference screen , Preference screen scrolling but the bottom buttons are not scrolling as they are not part of preferences screen ,I am using this code to add two views one as preference-screen and other one to adding button

`addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreferences);

 setContentView(R.layout.preferencessetting);`

[image: Filter and Audio source are the part of Preferences and DropBox sync is another Layout]

I want to do as button should scroll with presences screen component .
anyone can guide how I can handle this case ?

Comment: This may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen.

Comment: Hi sachin003 thanks but the link you posted that is nice discussion but not solving my issue,Problem is that when I do the android screen in Landscape code it not showing my button even it's scrolling but not showing the bottom button .I read the given link discussion twice for better understanding but still same problem ..