# How to add custom layout in preference activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a button to PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen)

I want to add custom view at the bottom of the preference activity and also want to implement onClick of the views added in the screen? When i try to add view using layout inflator in preference screen it is always place at top of the preference view. But I want to show my view at bottom of the preference screen.

Below is the code snippets for adding layout in preference activity.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_preference, null, true);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
addContentView(view,rl);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout parent = new RelativeLayout(this);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) generateLayoutParams(null);
    params.setMargins(35, 35, 0, 0);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);

    parent.addView(button);

    setContentView(rl);
}
```

Comment: i hope this answer will help you

Comment: this fails for me (params is null and after I get `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`)

Comment: Sorry, That was long time ago, I will update my answer.