# Unclickable button set on a preference activity

Tags: android

I just set a button on a preference activity from one the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen). My main issue is that this button is unclickable while the other elements of the preference activity is click able.

I created a simple example to demonstrate my dilemma it should show the same symptoms as you copy and paste.

```
public class preferenceTest extends PreferenceActivity{

private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I got clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
 public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preftest);
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }


}
```

res\layout\activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_weight="10"/>

<Button android:text="This is a button on bottom of all preferences."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

res\xml\preftest.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="New Title"
    android:summary="Title">

    <ListPreference 
        android:key="list1"
        android:title="List one"
        android:summary="List1"
        />

    <ListPreference 
        android:key="list2"
        android:title="List two"
        android:summary="List2"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="check1"
    android:title="check1"
    android:summary="CheckBox Test"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to add a button in a PreferenceActivity, but what you can do is add a plain `Preference` and then make that clickable through the activity code.

For instance, on your `preferences.xml`

```
<Preference
        android:key="@string/pref_key_dummy_pref_button"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_dummy_pref_button" />
```

Then, on your PreferenceActivity, create a Preference object:

```
Preference mDummyButtonPref;
```

Initialize it from onCreate:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
mDummyButtonPref= findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_dummy_pref_button));
```

Then, add override onPreferenceTreeClicked to handle clicks:

```
@Override
@Deprecated
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
        Preference preference) {
    if (preference == mDummyButtonPref) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Dummy got clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution works great on mobiles(like Nexus 4), but doesn't work at all on tablets (f.e. Nexus 100)