# Preference Activity Vs PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, preferences

In preference Activity we can use these two methods `SetContentView(R.layout.main)`
 and `addXmlFromResources(R.xml.Preferences)` for customizing the preference screen. For example see this  [Adding a button on Prefernce Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen/3026922#3026922)

Is this possible in PreferenceFragment?

In PreferenceFragment, I have added `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.PreferenceScreen);` in onCreate method.
When I use onCreateView it's getting force closes. I have tried Layout Inflator also. It's 
not working.

So is this possible only on preference Activity? not Preference Fragment?

P.S- I am using support V 13 Library. So I have created Preference Fragment in Fragment Pager Adapter. Please don't suggest to me to create Preference Activity for preference Fragment

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
addPreferencesFromResource(int res);
```

in **both** `PreferenceFragment` and `PreferenceActivity`, inside the `onCreate()` method.
Bear in mind that `PreferenceFragment` should be used in **post Honeycomb** Android Versions as a replacement for `PreferenceActivity`.

If you want a custom-layout for your `PreferenceActivity`, you can call `setContentView()` in the `onBuildHeaders()` method, but **not** in the `onCreate()`.

Comment: Yes. Use the onCreate() method to call addPreferencesFromResource() for both Activity and Fragment. PreferenceFragment also has an onCreate() method.

Comment: @phillip Jahoda I am using support V13 library fragments i have added preference Fragment in Fragment Pager Adapter.So i could not initialize the Preference Activity..

Answer (score 0):

- If your app supports versions of Android older than 3.0 (API level 10
  and lower), you must build the activity as an extension of the
  **PreferenceActivity** class.
- On Android 3.0 and later, you should instead use a traditional
  Activity that hosts a **PreferenceFragment** that displays your app
  settings. However, you can also use **PreferenceActivity** to create a
  two-pane layout for large screens when you have multiple groups of
  settings.

[see this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)