# Unable to call methods with a button in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, preferenceactivity

This is my first time to use `PreferenceActivity`.

I have made a simple activity for a settings screen, and when I set up a button in the layout and set the `onClickListener` for the button, there are no actions nor are there any errors.

All I want to do is to send the user back to the main screen by pressing the button. Is there some error or some setup that I have missed?

The mysterious part is that neither the xml `onClick` nor the direct method call work. No actions, no errors, it does not even show a `Toast` (when altered for debugging). Is there anyone who actually used `PreferenceActivity` and used some widgets like buttons ?

Here is my sample activity for the Settings Screen

```
    public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

//This button doesn't work 
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setupid);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();



        }



        public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
        {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            }


        }

    }
```

Here is the xml layout for the Settings.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3498db"
        android:gravity="center"

      >


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Set"

            android:id="@+id/setupid" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you put the code to start your HomeActivity right at the start of your PreferenceActivity? Or show a `android.widget.Toast` inside your `onClick`?

Comment: I'm curious how you manage to get `PreferenceActivity` and `PreferenceFragment` together? `PreferenceActivity` does not support fragment, it extends from `ListActivity`.

Comment: It's possible. http://rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/

Comment: have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen/3026922#3026922?

Comment: I've seen the link user1587329, the answer seems  good, but it  hadn't solved my problem, and the answers are mostly deprecated.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help me out,especially  user1587329. I was able to solve the problem by replacing  getFragmentManager with addPreferencesFromResource().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't have to use the Fragment in the first place. All you have to do is to  use addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); under setContents View.

```
 public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
           //It is depricated but it works 
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setupid);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, //new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();



        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample! But I'm still curious about what I must use for the  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); since it is deprecated. However, it works so problem solved for now.